# Mongodb Generate unique random with resultset in Query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, random-access

i want to generate unique number with each document when i execute query.Below is my query that generate random number,but that number is same to my 20 result set. When again executing number is change but all 20 records have same numbers.

```
db.content.aggregate([
  {$match: {cid:8144974}}
 ,{$addFields: {'getrandom': Math.random()}}
  ,{$limit:20}
  ])
```

Is there any other way in which i can get unique random number?

Comment: Use uid from npm it’s more easier than you create yourself

Comment: @Jonathan,how to use npm with mongo query in mongo shell?

Comment: this should work `{ $addFields: { 'getrandom': Math.floor(Math.random() * 5456456456456) }}`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet.Not working.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet.not getting any error but resultset are same.

Comment: which framework you are using ? Nodejs?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet.apart from using any framework. i want to execute in mongo shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179089/discussion-between-5a01d01p-and-anthony-winzlet).